LangChain can't connect to MySQL in Ubuntu
I have a Ubuntu 22 server running LangChain and MySQL.
But LangChain can't connect to MySQL from inside this local environment  (code runs fine without exception, just won't print out any tables).
from langchain_community.utilities.sql_database import SQLDatabase
import pyodbc

db = SQLDatabase.from_uri('mysql+mysqlconnector://root:abcd1234@localhost:3306/test?auth_plugin=mysql_native_password')

print(db.dialect) # print out: mysql
print(db.get_usable_table_names()) #print out empty list: []

I further tested a regular connection works:
import mysql.connector

DB_HOST = 'localhost'
DB_PASS = 'abcd1234'
DB_NAME = 'test'
DB_USER = 'root'

def db_select(sql):
    
    con = mysql.connector.connect(host = DB_HOST, 
                                  user = DB_USER, 
                                  passwd = DB_PASS, 
                                  db = DB_NAME,
                                  auth_plugin = 'mysql_native_password')
    cursor = con.cursor(dictionary=True)
    cursor.execute(sql)
    result = cursor.fetchall()
    con.close()
    return result

a = db_select('select * from test_table limit 2')
for item in a:
    print(item) # this works

Any suggestions?

Have you checked whether you mysql is allowing external connections and that root user can access it from external? https://stackoverflow.com/a/14779244/460557

All privileges granted for root, plus I can connect from my local Windows to server.

In the 2nd, non-working example, you are not printing out list of databases - that code is missing from your question.

Problem solved, the reason is I installed mysql-connector and mysql-connector-python-rf to connect to MySQL. But mysql-connector-python is missing and should be the one to use. The LangChain code won't complain, only silently returns nothing.
Library difference:
What are the differences between mysql-connector-python, mysql-connector-python-rf and mysql-connector-repackaged?
